# iOS openGL image invert

Tags: ios, image, opengl-es

I'm trying to get create an inverse of an image, as part of an app.
I have implemented some image processing using openGL, following the GLImageProcessing demo from Apple.

My image is loaded from a .jpg, and loaded to a texture. I can happily modify contrast and brightness.

However, I am having unsatisfactory results when trying to create an inverse image (swap black for white).
I've tried a few approaches, but nothing works well on the device.
so far, I have tried;
    `glBlendFunc(GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_COLOR, GL_ZERO);`
this works well in the simulator, but on the device produces unstable results.
I have also tried;
    `glBlendFunc(GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_COLOR, GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_COLOR);`
this creates results as before.
Finally, I have tried;
    `glLogicOp(GL_XOR);`
this simply toggles between the image, and a black screen.

Can you suggest a (relatively) simple solution to invert my image?

Comment: Is it a grayscale image? how about writing a shader for that?

Comment: the images are greyscale, yes.

Answer (score 1):

How about this shader:

```
void main() {
    vec4 color = texture2D(texture, textureCoordinate);
    float inverted = 1.0 - color.r; 
    vec4 inverted_vec = vec4( vec3(inverted), 1.0);
    gl_FragColor = clamp(inverted_vec, 0.0, 1.0);"
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use OpenGL ES 2.0 (which you should be able to do safely, given the tiny fraction of 1.1-only devices in the wild), a simple way to do this would be to use my open source [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) framework and its GPUImageColorInvertFilter.

The following code loads your image from disk, creates a color invert filter, applies that filter, and then spits out a UIImage for you to use:

```
UIImage *inputImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpg"];
GPUImageColorInvertFilter *stillImageFilter = [[GPUImageColorInvertFilter alloc] init];
UIImage *quickFilteredImage = [stillImageFilter imageByFilteringImage:inputImage];
```

If you want to just display the resulting image to the screen, or use it as a texture, you can instead direct the filter to a GPUImageView or GPUImageTextureOutput to avoid some Core Graphics overhead (due to the generation of the output UIImage).

Answer (score 0):

If you have no transparency I suggest you first draw a white rectangle where the image should be (no texture, just pure white color). Then use `glBlendFunc(GL_ZERO, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_COLOR)` and disable the alpha channel `glColorMask(GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_FALSE)` and draw the grayscale texture. This should give you the desired effect if you have no need for transparency, in other case you should do the same using a FBO with a texture attached. Also after you draw the texture reenable the alpha channel.